# Data type of Dataframe column created using Faker

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, types, faker

`df` is a dataframe, created using the `Faker` library (used to generate datasets).

I want to assess `df`, storing the names of columns as string in one list; and their appropriate data types in a second list.

So far, I have:

```
columns = []
dtypes = []
for col_name, values in df.iteritems():
    columns.append(col_name)
    print(col_name)
```

I am stuck on the solution to detecting the data type of a given column. Could be stored as the data type class itself or as string literal.

Note: assessing the entire list `df.column.values()` is not necessary, as each instance/ record has to obey the same format Faker provides. Thus, assessing the very first column value suffices here.

Comment: Try `df.dtypes`. I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: Awesome, of course! Thank you haha

Comment: Love how Python makes everything easy

Answer (score 0):

My own proposed solution, using `df.types` as advised.

The crux of this being `str(type(values[0]))[7:-1]`, where I cast the class output as `string` and perform `slicing` of characters before and after my desired dtype (with single quotes kept).

```
columns = []
dtypes = []
for col_name, values in df.iteritems():
    columns.append(col_name)
    print(col_name)
    dtypes.append(type(values[0]))
    print(str(type(values[0]))[7:-1])
```